# Open source files in Sublime Text 2 in Firefox on OS X

Tags: firefox, sublimetext2

I am trying to set up Firefox to open source files in Sublime Text 2 on OS X without much luck.

I previously had Firefox configured to open source files in TextWrangler, but when I changed the configuration to use ST2 I get an error:

```
[JavaScript Application] The external editor cannot be found.  Please double check the path and try again.
```

..followed by the source file opening in the Firefox native source browser.

In `about:config` I have set `view_source.editor.external` to `true` and `view_source.editor.path` to both `/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` and `/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`.

What is the correct path to set for `view_source.editor.path`, or if that is not my problem what is?

Comment: This might or might not be relevant for your. If you are using Firebug try these tips (disclaimer: I am the author): http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/10/20/opening-files-from-firebug-in-sublime-text-2-or-any-text-editor/ - not sure if Firefox itself uses the same mechanism

Comment: Thanks for the tip (I came across it when I tried to find the answer myself), but I am looking to have the source files open when I hit command-u (as opposed to a context menu option).